# if condition failing inside SSH

Tags: shell, ssh, remote

I'm ssh-in to a remote machine (ubuntu) and trying to execute a little script in there.The script looks like this:

```
myfunction()
{
  input=$1
  count=$2
    ssh ubuntu@ip <<EOF
    if [ $input = "comment" ];then
      TotalCount=$count
      echo "TotalCount is $TotalCount"
    else
      echo "do something"
    fi    
EOF
}
myfunction comment 2
```

It SSH in to the server but prints empty

Output:
TotalCount is

I tried to escape the variable(TotalCount=\$count) since this is running on remote host. But didn't work

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to accomplish. The `input` and `count` variables are *local*, but you ware trying to print them remotely ?

Comment: `$TotalCount` will be expanded (to nothing) on the local machine, like all the other variables from the here-document (`$input`, `$count`). It's `$TotalCount` that you should escape `TotalCount is \$TotalCount`.

Comment: What makes you think that the `if` fails (as stated in the title)?

Comment: @glennjackman Once I get the TotalCount, my script is going to execute some other commands on the remote server based on TotalCount. I'm not only just trying to print remotely

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Solution

Try this instead:

```bsh
myfunction()
{
  input=$1
  count=$2
    ssh user@host <<EOF
    if [ $input = "comment" ];then
      TotalCount=$count
      echo "TotalCount is \$TotalCount"
    else
      echo "do something"
    fi    
EOF
}
myfunction comment 2
```

Notice that I added a backslash to `\$TotalCount` to prevent it from being expanded locally.

### Explanation

You want to escape the `TotalCount` variable, because that variable is being defined remotely. If `$TotalCount` is evaluated locally, then it will (probably) evaluate to the empty string, which explains why you weren't seeing any output. The `count` variable, on the other hand, is being defined locally, so you don't want to escape it.

Comment: @Kusalananda Explanation added.